# Removing orphans (SQLite 2) in dtree

Tags: sqlite2

I have SQLite 2 table:
Columns:
id, parent_id, value

```
1,0,'TOP FIRST' <---- top category "FIRST"
2,1,'11111-A'   <----subcategory of id 1 (FIRST)
3,1,'11111-B'   <----subcategory of id 1
4,0,'TOP TWO'   <---- top category "TWO"
5,4,'22222-A'   <----subcategory of id 4 (TWO)
6,4,'22222-B'   <----subcategory of id 4
7,100,'to remove'   <----- ORPHAN (There is no top category with id=100)
8,100,'to remove'   <----- ORPHAN (There is no top category with id=100)
9,4,'22222-C'   <----subcategory of id 4 (TWO)
```

How to remove orphans (id: 7, 8) from this table?

Answer (score 1):

You want to delete all rows for which no parent exists. This can be done with a [correlated subquery](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#cosub):

```
DELETE FROM MyTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM MyTable AS T2
                  WHERE T2.id = MyTable.parent_id);
```

Comment: It gives an error:
    SQL logic error or missing database
    near "SELECT": syntax error

Comment: It works in SQLite 3. In SQLite 2 this does not works.
I tried to use PHP (5.3.1) with SQLite 3 but it works only with SQLite 2.

Comment: If you really want to use SQLite 2, you have to implement this manually: read all rows; for each one, execute the subquery; and then delete the row or not.

Comment: Alone subquery also does not work (in SQLite 2).
I would prefer to use SQLite 3 but then:
PHP: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SQLiteException' with message 'SQLiteDatabase::__construct() [sqlitedatabase.--construct]: file is encrypted or is not a database'.

Comment: You'd have to convert the database file to SQLite 3 first.

Comment: I did it: Fatal error: Class 'SQLiteDatabase' not found.